# How to read info on voltage/beam energy, imaging mode, acquisition date/timestamp, etc. from image meta-data? (Tags)

Tags: tags, metadata, dm-script

DM scripting beginner here, almost no programming skills.

#### I would like to know the commands to access all the metadata of DM images/spectra.

I realized that all my STEM images at 80 kV taken between 2 dates (let's say 02.11.2017-05.04.2019) have the scale calibration wrong by the same factor (scale of all such images needs to be multiplied by 1.21).

> I would like to write a script which multiplies the scale value by a factor only for images in scanning mode at 80 kV taken during a period for all images in a folder with subfolders or for all images opened in DM and save the new scale value.

I checked this website http://digitalmicrograph-scripting.tavernmaker.de/other%20resources/Old-DMHelp/AllFunctions.html but only found how to call the scale value (ImageGetDimensionCalibration). I have a general idea how to write the script based on other scripts if I find out how to call the metadata.

*If anyone can write the whole script for me I would greatly appreciate your effort.*

Comment: Hi and welcome. I'm going to type an answer in a sec, but it is a bit longer so be patient. Just for other mods getting here: This is a perfectly valid question for the DM-scripting tag! Don't vote for closure!

Comment: Your question is a tiny bit *too* specific. Also: StackOverflow is ***not*** the place to ask others to write code for you. This is generally frowned upon. It is the place to *learn* how to do it yourself ;c) In this spirit, I will give an a bit more general answer here to get you started on your task. I'll concentrate on reading tags only here. It is also a good style on this site to rather have multiple questions with a single-topic than convoluted ones. So see if this answer helps you forward, and post *a new* detail question, when you have one.

Comment: Thank you for the general info on StackOverflow. Your detailed answer helped me understand how DM scripting works and I managed to write a script for my task.

Comment: Glad I could help. Have other detail questions on your quest to the "automatic batch processing" script been solved as well? If not, please post as separate questions. If you have a nicely working script, you might consider submitting it to the [DM Script database](http://www.felmi-zfe.at/dm-script/dm-script-database/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## All general meta-data is organized in the image tag-structure

You can see this, if you open the *Image Display Info* of an image. (Via the menu, or by pressing `CTRL + D`) and then browse to the "Tags" section:

[image: Example of Image Tags]

All info on the right are *image tags* and they are organized in a hierarchical tree.

How this tree looks like, and what information is written where, is totally open and will depend on what GMS version you are using, how the hardware is configured etc. Also custom scripts might alter this information.

So for a scripting start, open the data you want to modify and have a look in this tree.

> **Hint:** The following min-script can be useful. It opens a tag-browsing window for the front-most image but as a modeless dialog (i.e. you can keep it open and interact with other parts): 
> `GetFrontImage().ImageGetTagGroup().TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(0)`

The information you need to check against is *most probably* found in the `Microscope Info` sub-tree. Here, usually all information gathered from the microscope during acquisition is stored. What is there, will depend on your system and how it is set up.

The information of the STEM image acquisition - as far as the scanning engine and detector is concerned - is *most probably* in the `DigiScan` sub-tree.

The `Data Bar` sub-tree usually contains date and time of creation etc.

## Calibration values are not stored in the image tag-structure

What you will *not* find in this tag-structure is the *image calibration*, i.e. the values actually used by DM to display calibrated values. These values are "one level up" so to speak here:

[image: Example of calibration values]

This is important to know in the following for your script, because you will need different commands for both the "meta-data" from the tags, and the "calibration" you want to change.

## Accessing meta-data by script

The script-commands you need to read from the tags are all described in the F1 help documentation here:

[image: F1 TagGroup]

Essentially, you need a command to get the "root" TagGroup of an image, which is `ImageGetTagGroup()` and then you traverse within this tree.
This might seem confusing - because there are a lot of slightly different commands for the different types of stored tags - but the essential bits are easy:

- All "Paths" through the tree are just the individual names (typed *exactly*)
- For each "branch" you have to use a single colon `:`
- The commands to set/get a tag-value all require as input the "root" tagGroup object and the "path" as a string. The *get* commands require a variable of matching type to store the value in, the *set* commands need the value which should be written.
  = The *get* commands themeselves return *true* or *false* depending on whether or not a tag-path could be found and the value could be read.

So the following script would read the "Imaging Mode" from the tags of the image shown as example above:

```
string mode
GetFrontImage().ImageGetTagGroup().TagGroupGetTagAsString( "Microscope Info:Imaging Mode", mode )
OKDialog( "Mode: " + mode )
```

and in a little more verbose form:

```
string mode // variable to hold the value
image img   // variable for the image
string path // variable/constant to specify the where
TagGroup tg // variable to hold the "tagGroup" object

img := GetFrontImage()                  // Use the selected image
tg = img.ImageGetTagGroup()             // From the image get the tags (root)
path = "Microscope Info:Imaging Mode"   // specify the path

if ( tg.TagGroupGetTagAsString( path, mode ) )
    OKDialog( "Mode: " + mode )
else
    Throw( "Tag not found" )
```

If the tag is not a *string* but a value, you will need the according commands, i.e.
`TagGroupGetTagAsNumber()`.